# invertendo uma sequencia long em c

Tags: c

Eu preciso inverter uma sequencia de numeros, por exemplo, se for inserido 1234, eu imprimo 4321. O código ta funcionando, mas pra entradas do tipo 0123 ou 1230 o zero simplesmente é "excluido", mas eu precisava que o zero também fosse apresentado na tela. Não consegui pensar ou achar uma solução pra isso, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
int main()
{
    long n;
    long inverso;

    scanf("%ld",&n);

    do
    {
        inverso=n%10;
        printf("%ld",inverso);
        n/=10;

    }while(n>0);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` precisa ser long? 0 a esquerda sempre será ignorado para long, isso é normal. 0123 é a mesma coisa que 123.
O mesmo acontece com 1230, inicialmente o 0 está lá, pois ele é 1.230, após inverter o mesmo acontece e ele passa a ser 321.

Comment: Para mim, com a entrada `1230` funcionou perfeitamente. Para `0123`, de fato, o 0 é ignorado pelo motivo explicado acima.

Comment: sim precisa ser long, essa é uma quetão do URI, numero 1984, pra quem conhece o URI...

Comment: Enunciado: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1984

Comment: Se você pede como entrada um número não pode ter um 0 no início.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o especificador 0* para especificar o tamanho do campo a ser impresso com zeros à esquerda.
Por exemplo para um campo de 5 posições:

```
printf("%0*lld\n", 5, 123);
```

No seu caso você precisa determinar o tamanho do campo que pode ser feito, por exemplo, imprimindo o número original em uma string (sprintf) e utilizando a função strlen de .

Comment: Eu não entendi mto bem como vou aplicar isso no meu programa, mas pelo que eu entendi esse `printf` vai colocar um 0 nas saidas de toda e qualquer entrada,o que não deve acontecer.

Comment: Apenas se o número a ser impresso não alcançar o número de algarismos definido no primeiro parâmetro (no caso o 5).

Comment: Veja teste em: http://ideone.com/cZG26Q